# How to make Gulp watch monitoring files?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulpfile

I have a simple `gulpfile.js`, that defines only two tasks, `buildLess` and `watchFiles`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

function buildLess(done) {
    const fileFilter = filter(['**/*', '!**/mixins.less', '!**/variables.less']);
    gulp.src('./public/less/*.less')
        .pipe(fileFilter)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
    ;
    done();
};

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch(['public/less/*.less'], gulp.series('build-less'));
    // gulp.watch(['./public/less/*.less'], gulp.series(buildLess));
};

gulp.task('build-less', buildLess);
gulp.task('watch-files', watchFiles);
```

The first one (`$ gulp build-less`) is working fine. The `watchFiles` (`$ gulp watch-files`) can be started and doesn't cause any errors, but changes on the `public/less/style.less` are ignored.

**What is wrong at this `gulpfile.js` and how to get the `watch-files` task working?**

Answer (score 0):

The [`gulp.series`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series/) API allows you to pass a string of a *previously registered task*. In your code, you haven't registered `build-less` yet.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

function buildLess(done) {
    const fileFilter = filter(['**/*', '!**/mixins.less', '!**/variables.less']);
    gulp.src('./public/less/*.less')
        .pipe(fileFilter)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
    ;
    done();
};

gulp.task('build-less', buildLess);

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch(['public/less/*.less'], gulp.series('build-less'));
    // gulp.watch(['./public/less/*.less'], gulp.series(buildLess));
};

gulp.task('watch-files', watchFiles);
```

I would note that Gulp does not recommend using the [`gulp.task`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/task/) API anymore to register tasks, but [instead to use `exports`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks).

Secondly, you don't need `gulp-watch`, as gulp now comes with its own [`gulp.watch`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch) method (which you are already using).

Lastly, you should make sure to your [correctly signaling async completion](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion) in your `buildLess` function. Below, I've changed that function to [return a Stream](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#returning-a-stream), rather than [calling a `done()` callback](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-an-error-first-callback) since as you have it written, you have a race condition where `done()` may be called before the Less compilation has finished.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

function buildLess() {
    const fileFilter = filter(['**/*', '!**/mixins.less', '!**/variables.less']);
    return gulp
        .src('./public/less/*.less')
        .pipe(fileFilter)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'));
}
exports['build-less'] = buildLess;

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch(['public/less/*.less'], buildLess);
}
exports['watch-files'] = watchFiles;
```

Overall, I'd go through [Gulp's documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start). They [recently updated their website](https://twitter.com/gulpjs/status/1250653052698148864), and updated their documentation along with it. Going through that might clear up some other questions you may be having.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! To be honest, I don't think, the problem is, that `build-less` is not registered. Why? 1. `watchFiles()` is a function. Yes, it's _defined_ before the task `build-less` is defined -- but it's _used_, when the task is already defined. 2. I also tried `gulp.series(buildLess)` (see the commented out line in my code) -- and it also doesn't work. Now I tried our both solutions from your answer. But they are not working for me. Actually I think, perhaps it's not a code problem at all. Could you please test, whether my original code is also working for you. Thanks

Comment: Actually your original code did work for me in a simple test environment, but I think you may have some race conditions.

One thing, what version of gulp do you have specified in your **package.json** file?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! To you question: **`package.json`**: `"gulp": "^4.0.2"` and `"gulp-cli": "^2.2.0"`, **`package-lock.json`**: `"gulp": { "version": "4.0.2"` and `"gulp-cli": { "version": "2.2.0"`.